# 401 Error on api requests on production only

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-6, laravel-passport

Laravel 6 API requests works fine on local server but returns 401 on remote server.
Both are nginx driven with php-fpm.
Authentificates by https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: could you add your authorization code

Answer (score 0):

Migrated project to Laravel 7 and Passport 9 and problem was solved.
Was faster to migrate project in my case: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade